# How could I access wpf window resoures

Tags: c#, wpf, modern-ui

I have this xaml

```
<mui:ModernWindow x:Uid="mui:ModernWindow_1" x:Class="App1.HomePage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
  xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
  ContentSource="/Window1.xaml"
  Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowState="Maximized" MenuLinkGroups="{Binding menuLinkGroups}">
    <mui:ModernWindow.Resources>
        <sys:String x:Key="ApplicationName">Bla Bla</sys:String>
    </mui:ModernWindow.Resources>
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource ContentRoot}" Name="mainGrid">
    </Grid>
</mui:ModernWindow>
```

I need to reference current window resources, so I used this:

```
object obj = this.Resources["ApplicationName"];
```

But **this.Resources** doesn't have any resource! so **obj** is always null. How could I reference this window resources?

Comment: Where did you write that code?

Comment: Please check if there are any Resources `this.Resources.Count`

Comment: @user3222589: do you mean you wrote the code as an eventhandler for a button, in the codebehind for `App1.HomePage`?

Comment: Thanks Dan, problem was solved and I have posted the solution, To answer your question, the button is in another window, and public method that handles this is called from the other window button event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that `this` is a `FrameworkElement`, like a `Window`, a `Grid`, a `Button` or something like that.

```
object obj = this.TryFindResource("ApplicationName");
```

Comment: hmm… strange… I saw on Codeplex that ModernWindow inherits from Window (which inherits from `FrameworkElement`) and that neither Resources nor TryFindResource is overriden.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below mentioned code

```
var MainGrid=Application.Current.FindResource("strApp")
```

or

```
this.FindResource("ApplicationName")
```

Comment: MainGrid? MainGrid is not a resource it's a grid.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `this` is a control...

```
var parent = Window.GetWindow(this)
```

Will get the window the control is currently on, you should then be able to access the resources like you already did

```
parent.Resources["ApplicationName"];
```

Comment: the same! can't find reasonable reason for this.

Comment: I'd suspect ModernWindow is doing something 'smart' with the ResourceDictionaries (caching them or something) then and it is what is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, I find the solution (I forget to update the localized dll).

I cleaned and rebuilt solution, used locbaml.exe again to generate new localized dll.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind in the XAML and not in the code behind.

"res" is the namespace where the resources file is located.

In your example the namespace alias is "local":

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project.Resources"
```

So your code should look like:

```
<Page Title ="{x:Static local:localStrings.step1Description}" />
```

Where:

"local" is the namespace alias where the resources file is located.

"localStrings" is the name of the resource file.

"step1Description" is an entry in the resource file.

Comment: In my case, I'm handling this in code behind to generate a user-specific menu, menu strings are stored as resources to give multilingual support, if you have a better approach to bind directly please point me to.